# Render functional component that is reliant on useState, on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I am new to react, hooks and functional components.

I have a **Dashboard** component wrapped in a context provider **Store**, when **Store** loads it establishes a socket connection, the server then sends the required DB (**allChats**) data to the client, which is loaded by a reducer **dispatch**.

In **Dashboard** i get the keys (**topics**) from **allChats**, i have a list that's populated by a key (**activeTopic**) value in **topics**.
**activeTopic** is hooked with **useState**, initial value is supposed to be the first key entry in **topics**.

Problem is **Dashboard** renders before the client recieves the DB data, i need to render **Dashboard** either after the DB payload is recieved or render a placeholder until **allChats** is updated in the Context provider and re-render is triggered.

I can't conditionally set the useState hook, and when i try to return render contents conditionally it throws undefined errors because the variable assignments are happening after the render is triggered.

App.js

```
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Store from './Store'

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Store>
        <Dashboard />
      </Store>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Store.js

```
let socket;

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    //Replace state with DB payload
    case 'LOAD_MESSAGES':
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default function Store(props) {
  //Hook reducer for DB data
  const [allChats, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {});

  if (!socket) {
    socket = io(':3001');
    //listen for DB data from server upon connection
    socket.on('initialize', function(msg) {
      dispatch({type: 'LOAD_MESSAGES', payload: msg})
    })
  }

  return (
  <CTX.Provider value={{allChats}}>
    {props.children}
  </CTX.Provider>
  )
}
```

Dashboard.js

```
export default function Dashboard() {

  const classes = useStyles();
  //Import DB data
  const {allChats} = React.useContext(CTX);
  //Get keys from DB data
  const topics = Object.keys(allChats);
  //Hook activeTopic, initialise with the first key entry
  const [activeTopic, changeActiveTopic] = React.useState(topics[0]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {
        //populate list with messages from activeTopic key of DB data
        allChats[activeTopic].map((chat, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <Chip label={chat.from} className={classes.chip}/>
                <Typography variant='h5' gutterBottom>{chat.msg}</Typography>
            </div>)) 
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am obviously missing the key concepts of the react, context and hook lifecycle. I don't want to hack out a solution i want to be able to handle it the proper way.
I would really appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a isLoaded flag to the allChats reducer.  Then, you can use that in the dashboard to show `<div>loading</div>` or the loaded chat view above.

Comment: Yes thank you that is elegant, i also put the allChats list component in another file aswell as the React.useState(topics[0]); so that way activeTopic initial state is only called when the component is loaded.